# Remove unique constrant and make username nullable in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a series of classes I have overridden for use in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 so that they use the email address field rather than the email field.

When trying to create a user it says `The UserName field is required.` I have tried overriding the UserName field in my `ApplicationUser` class which inherits from `IdentityUser` with `[Index(IsUnique = false)]` however this just results in a unique constraint and a non-unique index being created.

How can I override the `IdentityUser` class to make the username nullable and non-unique as I don't want to use it.

*Note:* I'm fully aware that you can store the email in the username field using the `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames` property in the `UserValidator` class. I really don't like this approach and would just like to remove this constraint so I can store the record without a username. I will modify any functions that I need that use the username to look at the email address.

Comment: According to current implementation of Identity Framework, it is not possible to use existing out of the box methods with your requirements. I would suggest you to use Username section same as Email and set AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames  = true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full implementation of the `IUserStore` - http://git.io/XZ3psA I wouldn't say that there is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to get rid of it is to implement your own `IUserStore`. Which sounds like a lot of work for almost no practical gain.

See UserManager has method `FindByNameAsync()` and `IUserStore<TUser, in TKey>` also requires method `Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)` to be present on the implementing class.

Also you'll need to create your own implementation of `IdentityDbContext`, or create required tables/relationships in your `ApplicationDbContext` to remove the uniqueness validation. Whic is also another load of work.

It is just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution just clear the user validator before using user manager and write your own logic. No need to override any class.

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,

    userManager.UserValidators.Clear();
```